# Extension items are grayed out, and there is no on/off slider button for extensions.gnome.org

Tags: gnome

When I go to extensions.gnome.org, all of the extensions are greyed out and there is no on/off slider in any of them. Another weird thing is that the reviews fail to load.

I am on gnome 3.9.90, with Ubuntu 14. I am using firefox, and do not have the Gnome Shell Integration plug-in enabled. Please help!